# Ignore freezed.dart and .g.dart files from lcov.info in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, lcov

Im trying to get a code coverage report following the below steps.

- flutter test --coverage
- genhtml coverage/lcov.info -o coverage/html
- open coverage/html/index.html

I want the generated files to be removed from the report. i treid..

```
lcov --remove coverage/lcov.info \ 'lib/*/*.freezed.dart'  \ -o coverage/lcov.info
```

But this does nothing. Still shows the report with generated files. I don't know whether if i'm doing this the right way.

Comment: Use `**` when you filter folder. I use this command and it work well:
`lcov --remove coverage/lcov.info '**/*.freezed.dart' ' '**/*.g.dart'  -o coverage/lcov.info`

Comment: this removed .g.dart files but didn delete a single freezed file.. Is there any other issue, where you able to remove freezed files also?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shell script to dynamically generate a list of files to exclude, based on their file extension, and then pass that list to `lcov` using the `--remove` option. Here's how you could do it for excluding `.g.dart` files:

```bash
# Build an array of exclude patterns
exclude_patterns=()
while IFS= read -r pattern; do
    exclude_patterns+=("$pattern")
done < <(find . -name "*.g.dart" | sed 's|^\./||')

# Now use the array when invoking lcov
lcov --remove lcov.info "${exclude_patterns[@]}" -o lcov_filtered.info
```

Explanation:

1. We first initialize an empty array called `exclude_patterns` to hold the list of files to exclude.
2. We use a `while` loop to read each line of output from the `find` command, which searches for all files ending in `.g.dart` in the current directory and its subdirectories.
3. The `sed` command is used to remove the `./` prefix from the paths returned by `find`.
4. Each file path is then added to the `exclude_patterns` array.
5. Finally, we invoke `lcov` with the `--remove` option, passing the `exclude_patterns` array to specify the files to exclude. The `-o` option specifies the output file for the filtered lcov report.

Now, when you run this script, `lcov` will generate a report that excludes all `.g.dart` files.